# Using WWW::Mechanize, how do I add a lower case header with an underscore?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

I'm using an API that requires me to use a header named "m_id" to the request.

When I use

```
$mech->add_header('m_id' => 'whatever')
```

WWW::Mechanize (or rather HTTP::Headers) “helpfully” changes the header name to “M-Id”.  Which doesn't work.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I thought I RTFMed before posting, but not well enough...
A second read through the HTTP::Headers [perldoc](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Headers#NON-CANONICALIZED-FIELD-NAMES) told me to use:

```
$mech->add_header(':m_id'=>'whatever');
```

and that does the trick.

Comment: HTTP headers are case irrelevant so if the application really requires a lower case header it might get in trouble with proxies normalizing the headers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich although it sort of makes sense that if an uppercase line is `-`, then a lowercase line would be `_` and thus with case-insensitive stuff it should not matter which one is used, that is probably not the case here. :D OP said it gets changed to `M-Id` with a dash, but they require an underscore.

Comment: @Steffen I couldn't resist the joke with the dash and the underscore, sorry about that. It's Friday after all. :)